# Typescript: Axios types

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I've created this class which uses axios's various methods to retrieve/send data. This will be a parent class of subsequent children which will use the general methods to make thing cleaner down the pipe.

I'll post the entire file below, but am highlighting a few of the type errors I'm getting and hopefully someone can help.

[image]

I thought errors were implicitly `any` or `unknown` so I'm surprised I'm even getting this error.

```
import {
    AxiosInstance,
    AxiosResponseHeaders,
    AxiosRequestConfig,
    AxiosResponse,
    AxiosError,
} from 'axios'

interface ErrorResponse {
    data: null
    status: number
    statusText: string
    headers: AxiosResponseHeaders
    config: AxiosRequestConfig
}

interface PayloadType<T> {
    [key: string]: T
}

export default class Axios {
    axios: AxiosInstance = window.axios

    async get<T>(route: string): Promise<T | ErrorResponse> {
        try {
            const { data } = await this.axios.get<T>(route)
            return data
        } catch (error) {
            return this.handleErrorResponse<T>(error)
        }
    }

    async post<T>(
        route: string,
        payload: PayloadType<T>
    ): Promise<T | ErrorResponse> {
        try {
            const { data } = await this.axios.post<T>(route, payload)
            return data
        } catch (error) {
            return this.handleErrorResponse<T>(error)
        }
    }

    async put<T>(
        route: string,
        payload: PayloadType<T>
    ): Promise<T | ErrorResponse> {
        try {
            const { data } = await this.axios.put<T>(route, payload)
            return data
        } catch (error) {
            return this.handleErrorResponse<T>(error)
        }
    }

    async patch<T>(
        route: string,
        payload: PayloadType<T>
    ): Promise<T | ErrorResponse> {
        try {
            const { data } = await this.axios.patch<T>(route, payload)
            return data
        } catch (error) {
            return this.handleErrorResponse<T>(error)
        }
    }

    async delete<T>(route: string): Promise<T | ErrorResponse> {
        try {
            const { data } = await this.axios.delete<T>(route)
            return data
        } catch (error) {
            return this.handleErrorResponse<T>(error)
        }
    }

    private handleErrorResponse<T>(error: AxiosError<T>): AxiosResponse<T> {
        if (error.response) {
            // The request was made, and the server responded with a status code
            // that falls out of the range of 2xx
            return error.response
        } else if (error.request) {
            // The request was made but no response was received, `error.request`
            // is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance
            // of http.ClientRequest in Node.js
            return {
                data: null,
                status: 0,
                statusText: 'Network Error',
                headers: {},
                config: error.config,
            }
        } else {
            // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
            return {
                data: null,
                status: -1,
                statusText: 'Unknown Error',
                headers: {},
                config: error.config,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does my answer fix your issue?

Comment: It did not @RobinThomas

Comment: Are you getting the same error or a different error?

Answer (score 0):

```
async get<T>(route: string): Promise<T | ErrorResponse> {
  try {
    const { data } = await this.axios.get<T>(route)
    return data
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof AxiosError<T>) {
      return this.handleErrorResponse<T>(error)
    }

    throw error
  }
}
```

The reason you need to check for the error instance is that by default its having the type `unknown`, which you cannot pass to `handleErrorResponse`.

---

Or you can update your `handleErrorResponse` to accept `unknown` values, which mean you dont have to update your `get` (and other helpers).

```
private handleErrorResponse<T>(error: unknown): AxiosResponse<T> {
  if (!(error instanceof AxiosError<T>)) {
    throw error
  }

  // ..remaining code
```